# OpenJDK not recognized in macOS Mojave

Tags: java, macos

I have a custom version of OpenJDK extracted in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines folder. But /usr/libexec/java_home says no JVMs installed and prompts to install java. How do i fix this?

Comment: How can we help you if we don't know what "custom" version of OpenJDK you have? We don't know where you got it, we don't know if it comes with special installation instructions... nothing.

Comment: It's an OpenJDK from my company. The issue persists for a "non-custom" OpenJDK as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the java directory into the PATH of the system. I found these two articles that could be useful to you:

- https://medium.com/@mamk2118/setting-up-environment-variables-in-macos-mojave-and-mac-os-catalina-27ea1bb032f3
- https://support.apple.com/pt-br/guide/terminal/apd382cc5fa-4f58-4449-b20a-41c53c006f8f/2.9/mac/10.14

Comment: I had to uninstall Oracle JDK (fundamentally all the JDKs) from the mac and install OpenJDK as the only provider. Still curious why the OpenJDK under - `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` wasn't picked up by default.